# Apache - setting up a subdomain

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I'm having trouble getting a subdomain working for an Apache Linux Install. Following is what I've configured:

DNS:

```
connect.goneglobal.com.
CNAME
54.251.35.112
```

Apache httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/connect.goneglobal.com
    ServerName connect.goneglobal.com
</VirtualHost>
```

restart httpd - this ip is registered to this server - works for other sites on this apache. (first time I've tried a subdomain).

Appears the issue is with DNS potentially and it doesn't seem to get to the site.

Note: I have an index.php in the Documentroot.

Note: there is an A record for goneglobal.com. which goes to a different hosting provider.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from here like the DNS entry hasn't propagated (if that's what you expected):

```
davidmarsh@server:~$ nslookup connect.goneglobal.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find connect.goneglobal.com: NXDOMAIN

davidmarsh@server:~$ nslookup goneglobal.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   goneglobal.com
Address: 117.104.160.130
```